# Need to group nodes based on 2 elements and sum a third. Key? Variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Thank you in advance for your help.
I have a large xml file and need to consolidate/sum the rows. I’ve spent much quality time with my XSLT For Dummies book and tried variations of many forum solutions, But I’m not even close. Any guidance you can offer will be most appreciated.

```
    <Report>    
        <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10025</emp>
            <cc>020107450</cc>
            <union>N10025</union>
            <fac>000002010</fac>
            <job>8062</job>
            <pay>RGR</pay>
            <hours>2</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10025</emp>
            <cc>020107450</cc>
            <union>N10025</union>
            <fac>000002010</fac>
            <job>8062</job>
            <pay>RGR</pay>
            <hours>110.27</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10025</emp>
            <cc>020107450</cc>
            <union>N10025</union>
            <fac>000002010</fac>
            <job>8062</job>
            <pay>RGR</pay>
            <hours>61.07</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
       <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10025</emp>
            <cc>020107450</cc>
            <union>N10025</union>
            <fac>000002010</fac>
            <job>8062</job>
            <pay>SAL</pay>
            <hours>2.01</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10058</emp>
            <cc>020107375</cc>
            <union>N10058</union>
            <fac>000002010</fac>
            <job>8085</job>
            <pay>SAL</pay>
            <hours>130</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10102</emp>
            <cc>020267515</cc>
            <union>N10102</union>
            <fac>000002026</fac>
            <job>8066</job>
            <pay>BLV</pay>
            <hours>31</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10102</emp>
            <cc>020267515</cc>
            <union>N10102</union>
            <fac>000002026</fac>
            <job>8066</job>
            <pay>SAL</pay>
            <hours>125</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10102</emp>
            <cc>020267515</cc>
            <union>N10102</union>
            <fac>000002026</fac>
            <job>8066</job>
            <pay>SAL</pay>
            <hours>125</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
        <Report_Entry>
            <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
            <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
            <emp>10102</emp>
            <cc>020267515</cc>
            <union>N10102</union>
            <fac>000002026</fac>
            <job>8066</job>
            <pay>VOL</pay>
            <hours>15</hours>
        </Report_Entry>
    </Report_Data>
```

My desired output is a single row for each emp/pay combination, with the associated hours totaled:

```
      N10025        000002010   8062    RGR 173.34
      N10025        000002010   8062    SAL 2.01
      N10058        000002010   8085    SAL 130
      N10102        000002026   8066    BLV 31
      N10102        000002026   8066    SAL 250
      N10102        000002026   8066    VOL 15
```

I considered not posting my xsl, but that’s bad manners. Don’t laugh too hard…

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:rd="urn:com.abcd.report/Report" 
     version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="emp" match="/Report_Data/Report_Entry/emp" use="text()"/>
    <xsl:key name="pay" match="/Report_Data/Report_Entry/pay" use="text()"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xD;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sep" select="'&#124;'"/>    

    <xsl:template match="Report_Data/Report_Entry">
        <file>
             <line>
                 <xsl:for-each select = "emp[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('emp',text())]">
                 <xsl:for-each select="key('emp',"'wd:pay')">
                      <xsl:if test="./text()=*/text()">
                           <!-- This is embarrassing -->
                     </xsl:if>
                 </xsl:for-each>                
             </xsl:for-each>    
           </line>
       </file>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet is tagged XSLT 3.0 - does your processor support (at least) XSLT 2.0?

Comment: `N10025        000002010   8062    RGR 173.34` looks like plain text to me, can you explain whether that is your desired output format or how it relates to the `line` elements in your XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT** 1.0 using *Muenchian Method*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="Report_Entry" use="concat(emp, '|', pay)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates 
      select="//Report_Entry[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', concat(emp, '|', pay)))]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
    <xsl:value-of 
      select="concat(union, '        ', fac, ' ', job, ' ', pay, ' ',
        sum(key('k', concat(emp, '|', pay))/hours))"/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Input**:

```
<Report>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10025</emp>
    <cc>020107450</cc>
    <union>N10025</union>
    <fac>000002010</fac>
    <job>8062</job>
    <pay>RGR</pay>
    <hours>2</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10025</emp>
    <cc>020107450</cc>
    <union>N10025</union>
    <fac>000002010</fac>
    <job>8062</job>
    <pay>RGR</pay>
    <hours>110.27</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10025</emp>
    <cc>020107450</cc>
    <union>N10025</union>
    <fac>000002010</fac>
    <job>8062</job>
    <pay>RGR</pay>
    <hours>61.07</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10025</emp>
    <cc>020107450</cc>
    <union>N10025</union>
    <fac>000002010</fac>
    <job>8062</job>
    <pay>SAL</pay>
    <hours>2.01</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10058</emp>
    <cc>020107375</cc>
    <union>N10058</union>
    <fac>000002010</fac>
    <job>8085</job>
    <pay>SAL</pay>
    <hours>130</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10102</emp>
    <cc>020267515</cc>
    <union>N10102</union>
    <fac>000002026</fac>
    <job>8066</job>
    <pay>BLV</pay>
    <hours>31</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10102</emp>
    <cc>020267515</cc>
    <union>N10102</union>
    <fac>000002026</fac>
    <job>8066</job>
    <pay>SAL</pay>
    <hours>125</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10102</emp>
    <cc>020267515</cc>
    <union>N10102</union>
    <fac>000002026</fac>
    <job>8066</job>
    <pay>SAL</pay>
    <hours>125</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
    <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
    <emp>10102</emp>
    <cc>020267515</cc>
    <union>N10102</union>
    <fac>000002026</fac>
    <job>8066</job>
    <pay>VOL</pay>
    <hours>15</hours>
  </Report_Entry>
</Report>
```

---

**Output**:

```
N10025        000002010 8062 RGR 173.34
N10025        000002010 8062 SAL 2.01
N10058        000002010 8085 SAL 130
N10102        000002026 8066 BLV 31
N10102        000002026 8066 SAL 250
N10102        000002026 8066 VOL 15
```

Answer (score 1):

**A short transformation that is fully in the spirit of XSLT** (push style):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vT" select="'&#9;'"/>

 <xsl:key name="kEntryByempPay" match="Report_Entry" use="concat(emp,'|',pay)"/>

  <xsl:template match=
  "/*/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kEntryByempPay', concat(emp,'|',pay))[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(union, $vT, fac, $vT, job, $vT, pay, $vT,
                                 sum(key('kEntryByempPay', concat(emp,'|',pay))/hours),
                                 '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Report>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10025</emp>
        <cc>020107450</cc>
        <union>N10025</union>
        <fac>000002010</fac>
        <job>8062</job>
        <pay>RGR</pay>
        <hours>2</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10025</emp>
        <cc>020107450</cc>
        <union>N10025</union>
        <fac>000002010</fac>
        <job>8062</job>
        <pay>RGR</pay>
        <hours>110.27</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10025</emp>
        <cc>020107450</cc>
        <union>N10025</union>
        <fac>000002010</fac>
        <job>8062</job>
        <pay>RGR</pay>
        <hours>61.07</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10025</emp>
        <cc>020107450</cc>
        <union>N10025</union>
        <fac>000002010</fac>
        <job>8062</job>
        <pay>SAL</pay>
        <hours>2.01</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10058</emp>
        <cc>020107375</cc>
        <union>N10058</union>
        <fac>000002010</fac>
        <job>8085</job>
        <pay>SAL</pay>
        <hours>130</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10102</emp>
        <cc>020267515</cc>
        <union>N10102</union>
        <fac>000002026</fac>
        <job>8066</job>
        <pay>BLV</pay>
        <hours>31</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10102</emp>
        <cc>020267515</cc>
        <union>N10102</union>
        <fac>000002026</fac>
        <job>8066</job>
        <pay>SAL</pay>
        <hours>125</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10102</emp>
        <cc>020267515</cc>
        <union>N10102</union>
        <fac>000002026</fac>
        <job>8066</job>
        <pay>SAL</pay>
        <hours>125</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <POSTING-DATE>02292016</POSTING-DATE>
        <pmtdt>2016-02-29-08:00</pmtdt>
        <emp>10102</emp>
        <cc>020267515</cc>
        <union>N10102</union>
        <fac>000002026</fac>
        <job>8066</job>
        <pay>VOL</pay>
        <hours>15</hours>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
N10025  000002010   8062    RGR 173.34
N10025  000002010   8062    SAL 2.01
N10058  000002010   8085    SAL 130
N10102  000002026   8066    BLV 31
N10102  000002026   8066    SAL 250
N10102  000002026   8066    VOL 15
```